# Save JSON object to MongoDB inside String field

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I'm working with Mongodb(mongoose) and node.js (express.js).
The model of DB is:

```
var messageSchema   = new Schema({
    _channel: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Channel', required: true },
    _user : { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    datetime: { type: Date, required: true },
    messageType: { type: String, required: true },
    publish: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    content: {
        title: String,
        text: String,
    }
});
```

I want save JSON object inside text field (string).
The JSON object is this:

```
{ event: 'push',
  repository: { id: 53012902, name: 'RestAPI' },
  ref: 'refs/heads/master',
  commits: 
   [ { id: 'a10202e5b5157ae5ccd2d77d7d578046693ae404',
       url: 'https://github.com/1izpena/RestAPI/commit/a10202e5b5157ae5ccd2d77d7d578046693ae404',
       author: '1izpena' } ],
  sender: { login: '1izpena', html_url: 'https://github.com/1izpena' } }
```

I convert this in String, but the result is:

```
{"event":"push","repository":{"id":53012902,"name":"RestAPI"},"ref":"refs/heads/master","commits":[{"id":"a10202e5b5157ae5ccd2d77d7d578046693ae404","url":"https://github.com/1izpena/RestAPI/commit/a10202e5b5157ae5ccd2d77d7d578046693ae404","author":"1izpena"}],"sender":{"login":"1izpena","html_url":"https://github.com/1izpena"}}
```

And this result is not a String, I need to keep the same format to parse it later as json object. 
Any idea?
Many thanks

Comment: How did you convert it? `JSON.stringify()` should result in an actual string.

Comment: `typeof JSON.stringify({...your object..})` returns string.

Comment: What are you using to convert into a string, JSON.stringify ?

Comment: Yes, and after JSON.parse to convert JSON again

Comment: Well, if it does not work to get it into the database as a json, I will make the test with typeof JSON.stringify({ }) Many thanks